# Escape Print pop up in codeception

Tags: javascript, php, popupwindow, codeception

i am using codeception in my case when i click on next BTN there is a print pop up apear and can not complite my test 
i try to use the below code :

```
   $I->click('next'); 
   $I->wait('5');
   $I->cancelPopup('window.print');
```

but dose not work  also i try to use  cancelPopup function as below :

```
   1- $I->cancelPopup();
   2- $I->cancelPopup('window.print()');
   3- $I->cancelPopup('window.print');
```

but same case can anyone tell me how can i escape the print popub ?